# unrecognized expression: [name=name[first][]]

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a jquery form validation code. That script is working fine if element name is single but if it is an array like below:

```
<form name="test" id="test">
<input type="text" name="name[first][]" />
<input type="text" name="name[first][]" />
<input type="text" name="name[first][]" />
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
```

validation script is not working, it always return this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=name[first][]]
```

You can see my code on this jsfiddle link:
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wdr9b/8/)

Comment: can u show validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the attribute value:

```
$('[name="name[first][]"]')
```

You can only leave the quotes out when the name is simple like `foo`, if the name is `foo  $[][½½{}]  ]` then you must quote it for reasons I hope are obvious..

Comment: The rule is: if you're not sure, quote. If you are sure, you can quote anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`Putting Quotes on the name will solve your issue` and 
`To validate the all Textbox value`, You can also try like below :

Fiddle Example :http://jsfiddle.net/wdr9b/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit').click(function () {        
      $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){ 
            if($(this).attr("name") == "name[first][]"){
                if($(this).val().length <= 0) {
                    alert('field is required.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
      });    
    });    
});
```